A small cannibal chasing a woman inside an apartment
A woman has just bought a present for someone. It's a small wooden statue of a cannibal with a spear and big sharp teeth. It has a chain attached and a note saying the chain should never be removed.
I don't remember how the chain was removed, but later she doesn't find the statue. Looking for it, she discovers it is alive and is a terrible predator hunting her. The cannibal bit her on the neck and caused her some other wounds. She spent all the movie fighting or escaping from the cannibal inside the apartment. She finally got him burned inside an oven.
At the end, she calls someone and tells something like "I'm waiting for you". She starts picking the floor with a big knife while from her mouth begin to grow many sharp teeth.
Since the story is not very long, I guess it is just a storyline in a bigger movie. 
I saw this movie on TV 30 or 40 years ago in Venezuela. It was a color movie.

This is from Trilogy of Terror, 1975, a movie consisting of three unrelated stories but starring the same actress. One of them is called Amelia, and that's the one you are looking for. Amelia brings home a doll that contains the spirit of an aboriginal warrior. The spirit is unleashed. 
From Wikipedia: 

... Amelia lives alone in a high-rise apartment building. She returns home after shopping with a package. Inside is a Zuni fetish doll, crafted in the form of a misshapen aboriginal warrior equipped with razor sharp teeth and a spear. A scroll comes with the doll, claiming that the doll contains the actual spirit of a Zuni hunter named "He Who Kills," and that the gold chain adorning the doll keeps the spirit trapped within. As Amelia makes a call to her mother we learn that she suffers from her mother's overbearing behavior. Amelia struggles to justify her independence and attempts to cancel their plans for the evening because she has a date. The moment Amelia leaves the room, the Zuni doll's golden chain falls off without her knowing. ...





Yes. This is it. Thanks for the fast reply.

This is from one of the short story of Richard Matheson
